# Modular Exponentiation (Power in Modular Arithmetic)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

> Hello!
>
>  I am got stuck in understanding the concept of modular Exponentiation. When I need this and how this works.
>
>  Suppose I am calling the power function as : **power(2,n-1)**.
>
> How the loops will be executed for say **n=10** and also the time and space complexity for the below problem

```
#define m 1000000007

unsigned long long int power(unsigned long long int x, unsigned long long int n){

    unsigned long long int res = 1;
    while(n > 0){
        if(n & 1){
            res = res * x;
            res = res % m;
        }
        x = x * x;
        x= x % m;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return res;

}
```

Comment: Your question "How the loops will be executed for say **n=10**" is not clear. Can't you write the steps out on paper or use a debugger to see what happens in this special case? In any case, your values of **x** and **n** are too small for the modulus operations by **m** to take effect so that is not the best example case. Do you mean to ask how and why that function works in general?

Comment: yes @RoryDaulton. how this function works ?

Comment: Do a search for "exponentiation by squaring" which will explain everything except the `% m` lines, which are there to make everything modulo `m`. If there is something in those explanations you do no understand, then come back and ask for more detail.

Comment: note that: (a * b) mod m == ((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m   This relationship can be used to keep the intermediate values within range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the modulo laws on DAle's linked Wikipedia page (on your previous question), we can obtain two formulas:

[image]

From the first formula it is clear that we can iteratively calculate the modulo for `n` from the result for `n / 2`. This is done by the lines

```
x = x * x;
x = x % m;
```

There are thus `log n` steps in the algorithm, because each time the exponent of `x` doubles. The step counting is done by `n >>= 1` and `while (n > 0)`, which counts `log n` steps.

Now, you may be wondering 1) why doesn't this part set the value of `res`, and 2) what is the purpose of these lines

```
if(n & 1){
   res = res * x;
   res = res % m;
}
```

This is necessary as at certain points in the iteration, be it the start or the end, the value of `n` may be odd. We can't just ignore it and keep using formula 1, because that means we would *skip* a power of `x`! (Integer division rounds down, so e.g. `5 >> 1 = 2`, and we would have `x^4` instead of `x^5`). This if statement handles the case when `n` is odd, i.e. `n % 2 = n & 1 = 1`. It simply uses formula 2 above to "add" a single power of `x` to the result.