# Find the modo value

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

I have given a log value `Y` , i want to calculate the anti log of Y i.e

```
ans = (Math.pow(10,Y))%mod
```

where `mod = 1e9+7` and the anti log of Y will always be integer i.e
 Y is calculate as follow `Y= log(a)   a is very large integer of range 10^100000`

So for given Y i need to calculate ans ? How to do that considering the mod operation.

**My Approach**

```
double D = Y -(int)Y
long Pow = (long)Y

  for(int i=1;i<=Pow;i++) ans = (ans*10)%mod;

  ans = (ans*Math.pow(10,D))%mod
```

But it's not correct can someone suggest be efficient approach here ? BigDecimal can be useful there ?
**For Example:**

```
Y = 16.222122660468525
```

Using the straight forward method and rounding off i.e `Math.log(10,Y)` give me `1667718169966651` but using loops it's give me `16677181699666510`. I am not using mod now just explaining that there is an error.

Here `Y` is small so direct method works and we can take mod easily. if Y is range of 10000 it will not work and overflow so we have to used mod.

Comment: Just to confirm, the log here is `log(a)` or `log10(a)`? and why won't `Math.pow(Math.E, (Math.log(a)))` work to find the antilog?

Comment: @nullpointer it's base 10

Comment: Then what's wrong with `Math.pow(10, (Math.log(a)))`?

Comment: @nullpointer i have updated with an example

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste the results correctly? Are you sure that 1) you aren't missing an extra "6", and 2) the two results are a factor of *10* off?

Comment: You cannot use `Math.pow` for *modular* exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's should work

```
double D = Y -(int)Y
long Pow = (long)Y

for(int i=1;i<=Pow;i++) ans = (ans*10)%mod;

 ans = (ans*Math.pow(10,D))
 ans = Math.round(ans)
 ans%=mod
```

Comment: I don't think it's accurate when `Y` is large

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your judgement here - *the loop method is not at fault*.

The value of `a` in your example has 17 integer digits. From [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places), a `double` has ~16 significant digits of precision. Thus *both* the loop and direct calculations are in fact being limited by lack of precision.

(Just to confirm, using a [high precision calculator](http://www.ttmath.org), the value of `a` is `16677181699666650.8689546562984070600381634077...`. Thus both of your values are incorrect - unless you copied them wrongly?)

> Thus your loop method is not the problem; you just need a
>   higher-precision method to do the last step (calculating `pow(10, frac(Y))`).

---

As a side note, there is a more efficient way of doing the loop part - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566228/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/45567391#45567391) has more details.